# Set focus to input field, after select onchange in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, focus, mobile-safari, onchange

I've been looking at creating a new quantity selector for a project I'm working on and seem to be running into issues with setting the focus on an element after a select onchange.

```
var quantitySelect = document.getElementById('quantitySelect');
var quantityInput = document.getElementById('quantityInput');

quantitySelect.onchange = function () {

    switch (this.value) {

        case '0':
            break;

        case '10':
            quantitySelect.style.display = 'none';
            quantityInput.style.display = 'block';
            quantityInput.value = '';
            quantityInput.focus();
            break;

        default:
            alert('Change quantity to ' + this.value);
            break;

    }

};
```

The idea is that any value selected from 1-9, will fire off a new form action and add the requested quantity to a basket. If the value of 10+ is selected, then a new quantity input field will toggle and focus will be applied to that element.

```
<select id="quantitySelect">
    <option value="0" selected="">Quantity: 7</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10+</option>
</select>

<input type="tel" value="7" placeholder="Enter Quantity" id="quantityInput" style="display: none;">
```

Everything seems to work as expected in my testing, apart from iOS browsers - which don't recognise the request to change the focus to the new quantity input element.

I've put together a small JSFiddle of my current working: http://jsfiddle.net/cahamilton/w93qwLk3/

Any help/direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I came upon a similar issue with IOS, adding *e.preventDefault()* seemed to resolve it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32391405)

Answer (score -1):

Think it could be a user issue, have you tried turning it off and on again?